# SharePoint document permission problem

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have this problem, can you let me know if you maybe have a solution, or if possible can you test to see if this problem occurs to you too, as I am not sure if it is some kind of bug or if I am doing this in the wrong way.

I have a Sharepoint Site A.
In the documents library, I have folder B.
In folder B I have 3 Excel documents X, Y, Z.

I would like to make permission for User1:

- Read for Site A
- Read for Folder B
- Read for document X
- Read for document Y
- **Edit** for document Z

So, I place User1 in the Visitors group on a site/library level, and then all items in the documents library inherit permission for Visitors (Read).

Then on document Z, I stop inheriting permissions, and then I grant User1 permission to Edit.

So it works on the Sharepoint site, when User1 opens Folder B in Sharepoint, he can view all other documents, he can only edit document Z (in Office online).

However, if User1 opens the document in File Explorer and tries to open and save the document in Excel, the document can't even be opened (loading and not opening, option A with direct access), or it can be opened but can't be saved - message pops up that it can be saved (option B with a link with editing permission to document).

The only way User1 can open, edit and save the document Z is if I grant editing access to him to complete Folder B (but then I have to remove editing permissions to documents X, and Y (every other document except wanted Z)), which is a problem if I have many documents.

What I am doing wrong, can you test this on your site?

Comment: Can you share the steps you followed to grant edit permissions on document Z?

Comment: In Sharepoint, I found the document, clicked on 3 dots, 1) manage access, 2) advanced, 3) stop inheriting permission, 4) added user directly with edit permission. The user remained in the visitor group for the same file, but it doesn't make a change if I remove him. Also, I found out if I create another folder inside this folder, and give user editing permissions for that folder, than the file can be edited. Somehow it can't give permission for editing on a file if the folder in which the file is, is not with permission for editing